Auth logoutOtherDevices manually Laravel
I use Session Driver Database,
If instead of using
Auth::logoutOtherDevices($currentPassword);

, for example, I did it manually like this:
    $user = $req->user();
    $session = $req->session();

    // SessionStore is Model For `sessions` table
    SessionStore::where('user_id',$user->id)->whereNotIn('id',[$session->getId()])->delete(); 

Are there any security risks? Or is this method wrong?
I want to know what logoutOtherDevices does. Does it delete the sessions from the table or what does it do?

Is there any particular reasons on why you don't want to use the provided method?

I don't use passwords in my app

If you check the Source Code for the logoutOtherDevices() method, you can see exactly what it does. I can't tell specifically what it does (lots of other methods, events, etc.), but if you're using the DB driver for sessions, deleting any sessions for the User besides "this one" should be fine. Sidenote, whereNotIn() can be replaced with ->where('id', '!=', $session->getId()); you don't need to use a WHERE IN [...] for a single value.

I saw the source code but there were a lot of forks, but is it safe for me to delete the sessions this way?
